# Why is my watcher not firing - vue3 setup function watching prop array for changes in number of items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Why are the watchers not firing when the array changes? The template updates.

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  someArray: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => []
  }
})

const someArr = toRef(props, 'someArray')

// None of these are hit or write to console

watch(() => someArr.length, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
})
watch(() => someArr, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
})
watch(someArr, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
})
watch(() => props.someArray.length, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
})
watch(() => props.someArray, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
})
watch(props.someArray, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
})
watch(() => someArr.length, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
}, { deep: true })
watch(() => someArr, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
}, { deep: true })
watch(someArr, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
}, { deep: true })
watch(() => props.someArray.length, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
}, { deep: true })
watch(() => props.someArray, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
}, { deep: true })
watch(props.someArray, () => {
  console.log('asdasd')
  debugger
}, { deep: true })
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ someArray.length }} <!-- this updates as expected -->
    <ul>
      <li v-for="arrayObject in someArray" :key="arrayObject.id">
        <!-- this updates as expected -->
        <div>{{ arrayObject.something }}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am using Nuxt with SSR disabled.

Comment: Some errors in your code: **(a)** You have no imports; I assume this was because they were considered irrelevant, but it makes testing just a little more inconvenient, and I no longer trust that something vital is not missing. **(b)** `someArray.length` is invalid. `someArray` is a ref, so you need to use `someArray.value.length`. TS highlights this. **(c)** You have not showed us how you are using this component.

Comment: I'm using nuxt, so no imports needed. Nevertheless I'll try to get a codepen working.

Comment: It appears to work for me: [Vue Playground](https://dub.sh/OmmxTIJ)

Comment: Are you sure it's not an SSR issue?

Comment: I have SSR disabled. For some reason that Vue Playground link is just a blank page for me, errors in console. Thanks for your efforts to help so far.

Comment: The link indeed does not work: Dub.sh is stripping double slashes from the URL. I'll try find some other way to shortlink here (the URL is too long for a comment).

Comment: Here's a TS playground that has the link: https://tsplay.dev/m071nN. Sorry for the inconvenience, but it seems that it's one of the few shortened links allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
watch(() => props.someArray, (val) => {
  console.log('asdasd', val)
  }, { deep: true }
)
```

is working,try this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-734xnz?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyCustomName.vue,src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: I deleted everything and used this implementation and it worked. I scoured my source and don't see a difference, so it must have been something silly like a missing colon. This will still be useful for others, at least.